# Configuring Stub Resolver in RHEL 8: systemd-resolved not caching DNS queries

Tags: rhel, dns, systemd-resolved, caching

In RHEL 8, `systemctl list-unit-files|grep resolved` reports that ***systemd-resolved*** is both present and running by default.  However, `systemd-resolve --statistics` shows no ***name:ip*** mappings are being cached locally: caching statistics remain "0" even when I force resolution doing something with `ping www.redhat.com` or `systemd-resolve www.redhat.com 127.0.0.1`

Why is ***resolved*** not caching previously resolved ***name:ip*** mappings locally?!?!?

[image: Caching tests annotated screenshot PRE changes]

Answer (score 1):

The fix is simple:  you need to reference `resolved` as a source of DNS resolution in ***/etc/nsswitch***.

Add "***resolve***" to the hosts directive, making it first in the list. So the ***hosts*** entry in ***/etc/nsswitch*** should look as below:

```
hosts:      resolve files dns myhostname
```

Let's see what happens after we make the change to ***/etc/nsswitch***:

[image: Caching tests annotated screenshot POST Changes]